# CSS not working for button appearence - Internet Explorer

Tags: css, html, css-float

I Have the following HTML and CSS for the current scenerio:

[image]

As you can see, the search textbox and the filter dropdown are appearing perfectly in-line. But the button is appearing down.

Here is the HTML code for all the 3 controls:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="search_result_div">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" style="width:200px;" id='searchButton' value="some text"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;in&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <select id="filterDropdown">
                        <option value="all" selected="selected">All Areas</option>
                        <option value="docs">Documents</option>
                    </select>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a onclick="return callSearch();" class="btn" id="searchButton" href="../sys/SearchResults.aspx?q="><span>Search</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the CSS for all the controls:

```
.search_result_div a.btn 
    {
      background: url("/images/bg_btn_left.gif")  no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
      display: inline !important;
          float: none;
      font-size: 11px !important;
      line-height: 21px !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
      outline: medium none;
      padding: 3px 0 3px 2px !important;
      text-indent: inherit !important;
    }

 .search_result_div a.btn span 
    {
        background: url("/images/bg_btn.gif") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;
        font-weight: bold !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 4px 8px 4px 6px !important;
    }
```

Note: The button is divided into two images.

bg_btn_left.gif : 
[image]

bg_btn:
[image]

Please suggest where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Hey now give to input{vertical-align:top;} in your css file

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me where exactly I should place this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.search_result_div a.btn 
{
  background: url("bg_btn_left.gif")  no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
  display: inline !important;
      float: none;
  font-size: 11px !important;
  line-height: 21px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 4px 0 3px 2px !important;
  text-indent: inherit !important;
}

.search_result_div a.btn span 
{
    background: url("bg_btn.gif") no-repeat scroll right top transparent;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 4px 8px 4px 6px !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its one of the problems I had to go through myself. I think I solved it by setting all default  margins and paddings to zero. See if that helps you.

```
*{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
```

or if its a problem of aligning use

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Answer (score 1):

For inline elements, you can use the *vertical-align: middle;* CSS property to align verticaly.

Answer (score 1):

look here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/YUXxf/ 
your code is working as you wish but i think the image has a top border bigger which is pushing the image downwards..

Comment: Its working in Firefox but the image is appearing towards down on the right side. But in IE it gets totally hidden as the image I have uploaded. Are you getting this correctly in IE ?

Comment: oh sorry, i didnot see your comment. yeah i did it in FF.

Comment: in IE also the same correct sight. please check your image borders and image quality itself. it should work so as in this fiddle..

Answer (score 1):

I always add this css file [css.reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to my project to make sure i don't use the default css settings defined by the browser.

Comment: I cannot do this since different teams is owing the CSS except the search CSS which is owned by my team. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hey i think you should give to some properties your `.search_result_div a.btn`

as like this

```
input{
vertical-align:top;
}
.search_result_div a.btn{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
*display:inline; // for ie
}
```